# How to implement MainActivity card view menu with fixed items?

Tags: android, android-cardview

what should i use to implement 4 fixed item menu, from which user will go to next activity ? Those 4 card views should be the same size and all visible without scrolling.

I would like to use card view, but I don't know if I should put it into RecyclerView or make 4 individual card views.

Thanks for help

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the number of cardviews is only 4 and they are fixed then no need for a recyclerview. Put them one below the other. Use a LinearLayout and set its orientation to vertical. Put all the cardviews inside this LinearLayout.

Then you can set onClick listeners on each CardView separately to take you to the desired Activity.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fix four layout using cardview.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"

            />

        <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:text="dsafdaf"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"

            />

        <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:text="dsafdaf"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"

            />

        <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:text="dsafdaf"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"

            />

        <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:text="dsafdaf"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```